# Select users that opened the App for the first time and their following visits

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I want to select the users that made their first visit to our App using 
`event.name = "first_open"` along with their subsequent visits using 
`event.name = "user_engagement"` during the following weeks.

The query I came to so far is:

```
SELECT user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS id,
    FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%W', PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event.date)) AS period,
    event.name
FROM `database.app_events_*`,
UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
WHERE event.name IN ("first_open", "user_engagement")
AND (_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20180205' AND '20180330')
GROUP BY id, period, event.name
HAVING COUNT(id) >=2
ORDER BY id asc
```

But it includes the regular users that have not opened the App for the first time during that period. How do I exclude these?

Comment: You say: "it includes the regular users that have not opened the App for the first time during that period. How do I exclude these?” ---- > If event.name is “user_engagment”, and is between that times it will appear even though first_open not between that time. So couldn't your WHERE statement look  something like this:"WHERE (( name = "first_open" AND date BETWEEN ('20180205' AND '20180330')) AND (name=”user_engagement” AND date BETWEEN ('20180205' AND '20180330'))) 
"

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding your event structure or tracking logic it will be hard to optimize my response, but basically the approach I would take is either a sub-query on the ID field (e.g. `id in ( select id from ... where event_name = 'first_open'`) instead of a single query that looks for both; OR if you want to make sure that the events actually happened at a later time (assuming that you are also tracking `user_engagement` during the first session), use a self-join that checks for equal IDs but only later events based on the timestamp of the event, or session identifier.

Comment: `first_open`is when a user opens the App for the first time and `user_engagement`is when the user uses the App. 
I tried your sub-query idea and I replaced 
`WHERE event.name IN ("first_open", "user_engagement")`  by `WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM ``database.app_events_*`` WHERE event.name = "first_open") AND event.name = "user_engagement"`
 but it returns me zero results. Am I missing something? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Logically seems right - are you sure that there isn't an issue with your tracking?
Also noticed that you have a double grave accent(`) encasing your DB name, so just double checking that this is a type here and not in BQ

Comment: The double grave accent is only for here. The solution suggested by @Vesper returns results (maybe due to the use of the UNNEST function?) but it only returns sessions where users opened the App for the first time but not the sessions with  `user_engagement` in the following weeks.

Comment: Actually this query is part of a larger one in order to find a cohort for new active users. First I thought it might be easier to first solve the subquery but now I´ve created a question with the full problem there [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798909/query-for-weekly-new-active-users-cohort-from-firebase-using-bigquery)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
#standardSQL
SELECT user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS id, COUNT(*) as visits
FROM `data.source`,
UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
WHERE event.name = 'user_engagement' AND 
user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id IN (SELECT 
user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id FROM UNNEST(event_dim) AS event 
WHERE event.name = 'first_open')
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(id) >= 2
ORDER BY visits DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer returns results but it only returns sessions where users opened the App for the first time but not the sessions with  `user_engagement` in the following weeks. 
Actually this query is part of a larger one in order to find a cohort for new active users. First I thought it might be easier to solve the subquery but now I´ve created a question with the full problem there [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798909/query-for-weekly-new-active-users-cohort-from-firebase-using-bigquery)